# ASP.net button is clicked in every page refresh

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net button in my page, after I click the button, it is clicked again and again whenever I refresh the same page.

I tried;

```
if (!IsPostBack)
   {
   .....         
   }
```

for the click function of the button, but in this case button is not working.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnCommentSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="leaveAComment" onclick="btnCommentSubmit_Click" />
```

above is the button.

```
protected void btnCommentSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string cityID = BusinessClass.Default.findCityIDByCountryAndCityName(Request.QueryString["city"].ToString(), "url").ToString();
        BusinessClass.Default.makeComment(txtComment.Text, Session["userID"].ToString(), cityID);
        txtComment.Text = null;

    }
```

and this is the function.

Comment: Show more of your code, because it doesn't really make sense so far...

Comment: with F5, if I write the same address and refresh it is no problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button click event called again when page is refreshed using F5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558790/button-click-event-called-again-when-page-is-refreshed-using-f5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If don't get you wrong your problem is when you hit F5 after clicking the button. Trying to resubmit the form is the normal behavior and is not related to asp.net but to browsers in general.

F5 causes to re-execute last request to the server, in your case, a POST request.

A way to avoid this issue is implementing the web pattern [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix with a bit of JavaScript.

```
document.onkeydown = function() {
      if(event.keyCode==116) {
      event.keyCode=0;
      event.returnValue = false;
      }
 }
```

This would stop the duplicate resend when you hit F5.